# Using Class.forName() and instantiating the class

Tags: java

I have a database which has a list of class names that I want to put in a a `List<MyInterface>`.

I do this:

```
List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
for(...) {
    MyInterface obj = (MyInterface)Class.forName(myClassString).newInstance();
    list.add(obj);
}
```

This works fine.

Is there any way to cast the new instance into `myClassString` and not the interface?

Something like:

```
"myClassString" concreteObject = (myClassString)Class.forName(myClassString).newInstance();
```

Comment: This part can't be right: `new List<MyInterface>()` You can't instantiate the `List` interface

Comment: What would that change? The object's concrete type is of the type held in myClassString, since you invoked the constructor of that class to get an instance. Casting it won't change anything.

Comment: Because there are methods in the concrete class that are not in the interface that I would like to use. So casting it into the interface wont work.  I think I am going to have to do an if block...

Comment: @Oscar,  your right,  bad typing.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as long as you know the concrete class:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
for (...) {
    MyClass obj = (MyClass) Class.forName(myClassString).newInstance();
    list.add(obj);
}
```

...But it's a better object oriented practice to use interfaces instead of concrete classes, so I'd leave the code as it is - with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual class, don't use `Class.forName()`, just use `new`:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' as I read the question, the final classname knows, then use it directly.

Comment: i was expecting the drawback of not using it directly